# Поле с геттером без сеттера

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс, в котором я бы не хотел, чтобы его поля можно было менять. Не могу понять как это сделать. Такая конструкция не работает:

```
class Message
{
    public readonly MessageType MessageType { private set; get; }
    public readonly string Data { private set; get; }

    public Message(MessageType type)
    {
        MessageType = type;
        Data = null;
    }

    public Message(MessageType type, string data)
    {
        MessageType = type;
        Data = data;
    }      

}
```

Comment: "не работает" - а что делает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C#, модификатор readonly применяется только к полям. Чтобы объявить свойство - только для чтения, достаточно просто опустить объявление сеттера.

```
private MessageType fMessageType;
public MessageType MessageType { get { return fMessageType; } }
// или так
public MessageType MessageType { get; private set; }
```

Кроме того, в C# 6 появилась возможность опускать сеттер даже у автореализованных свойств. Такое свойство нужно проинициализировать в конструкторе, или прямо при объявлении, как это делается с полями.

```
public class Test {
    public string A { get; } = "B";
    public Test() {
        A = "A";
    }
}
```

Comment: Или так: `public MessageType MessageType { get; }`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так не скомпилируется. _Error 1 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.Test.A.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors._

Comment: Студию обновите :) Начиная с C# 6 это компилируется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вы оказались правы, поэтому я добавил про эту возможность в свой ответ.